# How can I ORDER BY the "most relevant" entries in this context?

Tags: postgresql, query, order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "my bookkeeping" WHERE
    ("timestamp" > $1::date - INTERVAL '7 days' AND "timestamp" < $1::date + INTERVAL '7 days')
    AND ("amount in USD" > $2::numeric - $3 AND "amount in USD" < $2::numeric + $3)
    AND "is final" = true;
```

The intention of it is to find the most likely entry in my own bookkeeping table which corresponds to the actual bank data which I'm comparing it against from their CSV dump. Oftentimes, both the date and the amount varies due to annoying reasons. My application basically feeds me the results, one by one, allowing me to "reject" until I "accept" one that matches.

Currently, it doesn't `ORDER BY` any particular order, so I might get the least likely candidate record first, etc.

But if I simply `ORDER BY "timestamp"`, `ORDER BY "amount in USD"`, or `ORDER BY "timestamp", "amount in USD"`, it will just order by the amount or time itself -- not in relation to the data being compared against (`$1` and `$2`).

How do I `ORDER BY` the individual "closeness" to my input variables?

Comment: You can use a service like `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14` to create tables and insert sample data that illustrates the problem. Update your post with the URL to the fiddle and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: First you need to more concretely define "*individual "closeness"*" to begin solving this kind of problem. I'm assuming you want to calculate *closeness* by `amount` and `timestamp`, but what's your criteria? Are they weighted? Is 1 day difference the equivalent of $10 difference?...etc.

Comment: @J.D. An item with a timestamp closer to the input timestamp is supposed to go higher up than one with a timestamp longer from it. It can primarily do this, then care about the amount, or combine them both if that's easier.

Comment: Ok so you want to match rows by their closest `timestamp`s then by closest `amount`s?

Comment: @J.D. As said, yes, if it's too complicated to make it intelligently "account for both at the same time".

Comment: You can account for both at the same time but you need to define the rules that evaluates that. For example it's easy to say two rows that are 1 day apart and $10 different are a better match than another row that's also 1 day apart from the first row but $20 different. But how do you evaluate two rows that are 10 milliseconds apart and $1 different compared to a third row that's only 1 millisecond apart but $10 different, or another row that's 9 milliseconds apart from the first row and $2 different? Basically you're trying to compare rows by X, Y criteria but what is the function of X to Y?

Comment: In other words, how does `timestamp` relate to `amount` in your function to compare rows to each other?...for example, is it a fixed linear relationship such that 1 Day = $10, 2 Days = $20, 3 Days = $30 etc? Or is it an exponential relationship, e.g. 1 Day = $1, 2 Days = $10, 3 Days = $100, etc? Basically you need to define the relationship between X and Y (`timestamp` and `amount`) to be able to compare two rows by both X and Y simultaneously.

Comment: @J.D. What is unclear about the question I asked and my clarifications?

Comment: @user17987204 Please see my last comment which states what's unclear.